# SQL left outer join select unmatched records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
question table
========================
question_id
1
2
3
4


user_answer table
========================
user_id  question_id
33       2
44       4
33       1
44       3
```

This code will return the question id (2 and 1)
what I want is to retrieve the other question id from table question so I want
the result to be (3 and 4)

```
   $fadi = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question
         LEFT OUTER JOIN user_answer
           ON user_answer.question_id = question.question_id
              WHERE user_answer.user_id = 33");

   Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
   while($info = mysql_fetch_array($fadi))
   { Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<th>question </th> <td>".$info['question_id'] . "</td></tr>";
   }  Print "</table>"; }
```

Comment: Change 33 to 44 in your SQL query

Comment: Use mysqli instead of mysql for new code.

Comment: no i want to retrieve unanswered question from the question tale for and then add question id to user id to be like this

user_id 33 44 33 44 33 33
question_id 2 4 1 3  3  4

Comment: For clarification user 33 has answered question 2 and 1 and user 44 has answered 4 and 3. Now you want to find out which question a user has answered? Could you put you query in words

Comment: @Mr.Radical no i want to found unanswered question for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Improved version.

```
  $fadi = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE  question.question_id NOT IN (SELECT user_answer.question_id FROM user_answer WHERE user_answer.user_id = 33)");

   Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
   while($info = mysql_fetch_array($fadi))
   { Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<th>question </th> <td>".$info['question_id'] . "</td></tr>";
   }  Print "</table>"; }
```

MySQLi version:

```
  $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
  if (!$link){ 
  echo('Unable to connect to database');
  }
  else{
  $fadi = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE  question.question_id NOT IN (SELECT user_answer.question_id FROM user_answer WHERE user_answer.user_id = 33)", $link);

   Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
   while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($fadi,MYSQL_BOTH))
   { Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<th>question </th> <td>".$info['question_id'] . "</td></tr>";
   }  Print "</table>"; }

  }
  mysqli_close($link);
```

See in action: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27b6f/21

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for are the words IS NULL:

```
$fadi = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question
     LEFT OUTER JOIN user_answer
       ON user_answer.question_id = question.question_id
          AND user_answer.user_id = 33
       WHERE user_answer.question_id IS NULL");
```

You can go one step further by only retrieving the question ID from the question table:

```
$fadi = mysql_query("SELECT question.question_id FROM question
     LEFT OUTER JOIN user_answer
       ON user_answer.question_id = question.question_id
          AND user_answer.user_id = 33
       WHERE user_answer.question_id IS NULL");
```

Comment: I agree with the answer above. See this in action: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95a0c/2

Comment: I added a primary key to the user_answer table because your key was a composite key.

Comment: +1. Yes, the anti-join pattern is the way to go, with an index defined `ON user_answer (user_id, question_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

What could be an answer is to take the same `mysql_query` you used 
then from `mysql_fetch_array` retrieve the 'question_id' values and finally, if you have the count of the questions (if not you can use mysql count), to use php function `array_diff()` to retrieve (from the incremental sorted array of integer values of question_id or from the array of question_id values from 'question' table) exactly what you want

Comment: Or, the query could be modified to efficiently return the specified resultset, whichever.